# HTML5 - flip book page transition

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Page flip effect for HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613515/page-flip-effect-for-html5)

Can anyone suggest me how to make page turn(like flip book/dog ear) effect page transition using Css3 or jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using CSS3 alone. Here's an example using Canvas.  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip/

Comment: Thank u all. clk the URL below. I need the same effect on page load

Comment: http://dev.sencha.com/animator/demos/pageflip/